# How do I change file names with `.py` extension to `.txt` withing folders and subfolders

Tags: python, file

I want to change files with extension ".py" to ".txt" for all files within folders and subfolders. 
What I did with my code is :

```
def py_to_txt(directory):
    for foldername, subfolders, filenames in os.walk(dire):
        print(filenames)
        for f in filenames :
            if f.endswith('.py'):
                base = os.path.splitext(f)[0]
                os.rename(f, base + '.txt')
```

and this code only changes the  first file extension in the parent directory and then throws the following error :

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-69-ed0d85ebad81> in <module>
----> 1 py_to_txt(dire)

<ipython-input-68-1efd842876ed> in py_to_txt(directory)
      5             if f.endswith('.py'):
      6                 base = os.path.splitext(f)[0]
----> 7                 os.rename(f, base + '.txt')
      8 

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'file2.py' -> 'file2.txt'
```

What is the right way of doing it ?

Comment: filenames contains name file and the directory path?

Comment: @GiovaniSalazar How shall I modify this code then ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing I might note would be that you're missing the addition of `foldername` to each filename `f` -- without that, you're asking it to delete files from your current working directory, not from their actual location.

Try:

```
def py_to_txt(directory):
    for foldername, subfolders, filenames in os.walk(directory):
        print(filenames)
        for f in filenames :
            if f.endswith('.py'):
                base = os.path.splitext(f)[0]
                os.rename(os.path.join(foldername, f),
```

os.path.join(foldername, base + '.txt'))

---

The issue here is that when you go to use `os.walk()`, it returns three items:

1. The directory it's currently traversing (we'll call it *base*)
2. The directories within *base*
3. The files within *base*

So if we have a folder:

```
py/
  1.py
  2.py
```

Running `os.walk('py/')` will yield:

```
('py/', (), ('1.py', '2.py'))
```

Note that those last items don't actually contain their own full path -- they're the last part of the path, the file's name and extension. As a result, if you want the absolute path to an object, you have to join the *base* to the filename, like this:

```
for base, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):
    for filename in files:
        full_path = os.path.join(base, filename)
        print(filename, 'is different than', full_path)
```

Comment: Not working. Raises the following error `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'file2.py' -> '/home/akash/Desktop/testfolder/testfolder1/file2.txt'`

Comment: @AkashDubey -- whoops, missed a reference to `f` in the rename call. Try now.

Comment: works like charm. Thank you very much. One question though, what was I doing wrong ?

Comment: What if I want to change every file withing folders and subfolder to a same extension but want the original ext as file_oldExtension.newExtension and convert them back to the original name.